# Diferencia entre objetos iterable, iterator y secuencias en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, objeto, iteradores

He visto que en Python 3 hay objetos tipo *iterable*, objetos tipo *iterator* y también hay *secuencias*. Mis preguntas son:

¿Cuál es la diferencia? ¿Todos se pueden recorrer en un bucle? ¿En todos ellos se puede acceder a sus elementos mediante índices? ¿Todos contienen elementos en memoria o son generados de manera interactiva?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es la explicación a cada uno de los tipos para aclarar la diferencia:

- **Iterator**: Un objeto tipo iterator es un objeto que representa un flujo de datos, el cual puede ser recorrido en un proceso iterativo, como un bucle `for`, dentro de una función `map` o `filter`, en la creación de una *list comprehension* o *generador*, o en una comparación `in`.

  Todo objeto *iterator* contiene implementado un método `__next__()` que es llamado en cada iteración devolviendo los sucesivos elementos del flujo de datos cada vez. El flujo de datos del objeto no tiene por qué estar guardado en memoria, sino que puede ser generado en tiempo real en cada iteración.

  El objeto *iterator* guarda un estado interno para saber cuál fue el último elemento obtenido. Así, en la siguiente llamada a `__next__()`, se obtendrá el siguiente elemento correcto.

  Cuando ya no quedan más elementos en el flujo de datos del *iterator*, la función `__next__()` lanza `StopIteration`. El estado interno no se reinicia automáticamente al llegar al final del flujo o al empezar a recorrerlo de nuevo. Es decir, sólo se puede recorrer una vez.

  Además, tiene implementado el método `__iter__()` que devuelve el propio objeto *iterator*. Esto es necesario para poder implementar bucles con objetos *iterator*, como explicaremos después.
- **Iterable**: Un objeto *iterable* es un tipo de objeto que devuelve sus elementos de uno en uno cada vez. Tiene implementado alguno de estos dos métodos:

  1. `__iter__()` que devuelve un objeto *iterator* a partir de este objeto *iterable*.
  2. `__getitem__()` que accede a cada uno de los elementos para índices empezando desde 0.

  Un objeto *iterable* no tiene por qué tener definido el método `__next__()`, En cambio, al tener la obligación de implementar el método `__iter__()` o `__getitem__()`, puede ser utilizado como argumento para la función `iter()` y así recorrer el *iterator* resultante.
- **Secuencia**: Es un objeto *colección* que tiene definido el método `__getitem__()` (además de `__setitem__()` o `__delitem__()` si la secuencia es mutable) para acceder a los elementos de la secuencia. El valor pasado por argumento a `__getitem__()` en una *secuencia* es un índice o un objeto *slicing*.

  Existe otro tipo de objeto *colección* llamado *mapeador (mapping)* que también tiene definido el método `__getitem__()`, con la diferencia de que el valor pasado por argumento es una clave única. Además, como las *secuencias*, si el *mapeador* es mutable tiene definidos los métodos `__setitem__()` o `__delitem__()`.

  La función `__getitem__()` se ejecuta implícitamente al usar el operador `[]` con el valor argumento de acceso entre corchetes.

  Tanto las *secuencias* como los *mapeadores* tienen definidos los métodos `__len__()` e `__iter__()`al ser ambos *colecciones*. El primero permite que se devuelva la longitud de elementos de la *colección* al ser pasada ésta como argumento a la función `len()`. El segundo es debido a que las *colleciones* son *iterables*.

  Las *listas* y *tuplas* son ejemplos *colecciones secuencia* que además son *iterables* al tener implementado los métodos `__iter__()` y `__getitem__()` (para índices empezando desde 0). Pero en cambio no son *iterator* porque no contienen el método `__next__()`

La **función `iter()`**, la cual forma parte de lenguaje Pyhton, devuelve un *iterator* a partir de un objeto que contiene el método `__iter__()`, o que contiene el método `__getitem__()` para índices empezando desde 0 (lanzando `IndexError` si el índice no existe). Si no contiene ninguno de estos dos métodos, entonces la función `iter()` lanza `TypeError` en lugar de devolver un *iterator* a partir del objeto.

La función `iter()` es llamada siempre implícitamente al iniciarse una iteración como un bucle `for`. A dicha función se le pasa el objeto *iterable* sobre el cual se quiere iterar, devolviendo un nuevo *iterator* que será recorrido. Por esta razón, los objetos *iterator* deben tener un método `__iter__()`: para que la función `iter()`, ejecutada siempre sobre el objeto a iterar antes de iniciar la iteración, devuelva el propio *iterator* (sin reinicializar su estado `__next__()` en cada llamada a `iter()`).

La función `iter()` también puede generar un *iterator* a partir de una función (objeto que tiene implementado el método `__call__()`) en lugar de a partir de un objeto *iterable*. Para ello, se pasa como primer argumento a `iter()` la función que será llamada sin argumentos en cada `__next()__`, y como segundo argumento el valor de finalización. El *iterator* dejará de dar elementos lanzando `StopIteration` cuando la función, llamada en cada iteración `__next()__`, devuelva el valor de finalización.

Por último, tanto `Iterable` como `Iterator` son clases abstractas definidas dentro del módulo `collections.abc` las cuales contienen los métodos abstractos `__iter__()` o `__next__()`. Por lo tanto, una instancia de una clase heredada de `Iterable` debe implementar el método `__iter__()` (haciendo que cumpla una de las condiciones anteriores para *iterables*); y una instancia de una clase heredada de `Iterator` debe implementar los métodos `__iter__()` y `__next__()` cumpliendo las condiciones de *iterator* explicadas anteriormente.

Comment: Disculpa, pero posteaste la pregunta hace 4 minutos y en el mismo tiempo posteaste una respuesta?, ya la tenías consultada?.

Comment: @juliansalas Sí, es una duda que he investigado por mi cuenta y me pareció correcto compartir la información obtenida con todos.

Comment: Es absolutamente correcto y loable que respondas tu propia pregunta como forma de compartir información, pero ten en cuenta que eventualmente puede molestarle a otros que mientras están redactando una respuesta vean que ya has publicada la tuya. Por una cuestión de "etiqueta" recuerda que al redactar la pregunta tienes un "check" para indicar que vas a responderla también, en cuyo caso pregunta y respuesta se publican al mismo tiempo y evitas cualquier malentendido. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Así lo hice. Publiqué pregunta y respuesta al mismo tiempo.

Comment: @juliansalas esto no solo se permite en todo [so],sino que se alienta a ello como forma de compartir conocimiento.Se puede ver esta entrada de blog del propio desarrollador del sitio:https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. Siempre que se siga el procedimiento que ha seguido Carlos (publicar la respuesta junto a la pregunta) y que no sean temas triviales(por ejemplo '¿Cómo imprimo por consola en Python?') serán bienvenidas. Gracias por compartir tus investigaciones Carlos, si tubieramos sección de Documentación como en [so] quedaría muy bién en ella.

Comment: @FJSevilla Muchas gracias. Todas las dudas que me surjan al estudiar Python y me toque investigarlas para resolverlas las subiré encantado.

Comment: Tal como dices Carlos tu pregunta es la típica duda que todo el mundo tiene alguna vez pero que no se responde de forma directa en la documentación oficial. Puede que todo esté en la documentación de Python pero de forma muy dispersa (una pincelada al hablar de listas, otra al hablar de `yield` y los generadores, etc), por lo que siempre es positivo hacer un resúmen agrupando los conceptos, más aún si hay escasa o ninguna información en Español. Aunque ya lo sabes, por si a alguien le surge la duda a esto me refería con "Documentación": https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics

Comment: @FJSevilla Exacto, lo has descrito a la perfección. Y la Documentación de SOen es genial. Puedes avanzar en el aprendizaje de un lenguaje de manera brutal con ella. Es una auténtica pena que no esté en español. No sé cómo de activa está la página SOes respecto a otros idiomas pero quizás, si sigue creciendo, terminen haciendo algo así para español.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para consultar y compartir tal información, realmente no sabía que era valido postear la respuesta al instante.

Comment: @FJSevilla Muchas gracias por infromarme sobre postear preguntas, responderlas y sobre el link. Es muy útil para compartir información, sería muy útil que tuvieramos Doc en SOes como en SOen.

Comment: @juliansalas Bueno, para ser sincero el motivo principal es egoísta: me documenté para solucionar mi duda. Pero redactarla me ayudó a entenderla mejor y de paso quizás le pueda servir a alguien.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez considera marcar tu respuesta como wiki de comunidad.

Comment: @Jorgesys Muy bien. Hecho.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez Te faltó poner que un contenedor debe implementar también un método `__len__()`, pues los contenedores "saben" cuántos elementos contienen, a diferencia de un iterable que puede ir generándolos sobre la marcha o podrían ser infinitos.

Comment: @abulafia Muchas gracias por tu comentario. He corregido la explicación porque los contenedores (Container) en realidad solo tienen como obligación implementar el método `__contains__()`. Son los objetos de tipo colección (Collection), del cual heredan los tipos secuencias (Sequence) y mapeadores (Mapping), los que tienen como obligación implementar el método `__len__()`. Si ves que algo está mal o no queda claro, no dudes en decirmelo. ¡Muchas gracias!